# What are these dark artifacts in this New Horizons image?

Tags: photography

[image]

Are these photographic artifacts of some kind and if so how would they occur?
They are almost the same exact shape and size.
It is a photo of the Kuiper Belt from the New Horizon space probe taken directly from [NASA web site](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/new-horizons-spies-a-kuiper-belt-companion).
If it is not a common photographic event then what could it be?

Comment: They’re present only next to bright stars, so I would suppose it has something to do with imaging captor “bleed” of the light to neighbouring pixels…

Comment: Looks like maybe the CCD is being read-out raster wise and the pixels following saturated pixels can't be read correctly.  Looks like some of the less-saturated pixels have the same effect, but shorter.  Also probably a lot of data compression going on with images from New Horizons.

Answer (score 6):

[Weaver et al. 2020](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2020PASP..132c5003W/abstract) discusses New Horizons [LORRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Range_Reconnaissance_Imager) instrument performance in detail.
The introduction says:

> The LORRI CCD incorporates anti-blooming technology
> to eliminate bleeding of the electrons along columns
> when bright targets saturate
> (i.e., when the signal in a pixel exceeds
> the full-well capacity of ∼80,000 electrons).

Otherwise the tails of bright stars would be white and blocky.
Figure 5, another deep image of a star field, explains similar artifacts:

> The brightest stars are saturated and have black tails due to amplifier undershoot.

[Jenkins et al. 2010](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...713L..87J/abstract), section 2, addressed a similar issue for the [Kepler](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/kepler/overview/index.html) mission:

> The analog electronics chain exhibits memory,
> necessitating the application of a digital filter to remove this effect,
> called Local Detector Electronics (LDE) undershoot.